# Depth first search & breafth first search implementation in C++

Tags: c++, graph, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search, pointer-to-pointer

I am a beginning level coder, and am coding dfs bfs, bt its reapetedly showing error,I have assigned an array of nodes for wich i have used pointer to pointer, however when i assign values to elements of each array member, its showing error.THIS IS THE ONLY ERROR ACCORF=DING TO ME,KINDLY HELP!!

```
 struct node
{

int dat;
int vstd;
struct node *nxt;
};

struct node **graph=(struct node**)malloc(5*sizeof(struct node*));

void initial()

{
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
       struct node *(graph[i])=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
}

struct node *head=NULL;
void visited(struct node *strt)
{
    struct node *temp;

for(int i=0;i<5;i++)

    {
        temp=graph[i];

        while(temp!=NULL)

        {

            if(temp->dat==strt->dat)

            temp->vstd=1;

            temp=temp->nxt;

        }

    }

}

struct node* find(struct node *gelem)

{

    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)

    {

        if(graph[i]->dat==gelem->dat)

        return(graph[i]);

    }

    return NULL;

}

void dfs(struct node *gelem)

{

    struct node *temp;

    visited(gelem);

    cout<<gelem->dat<<endl;

    temp=find(gelem);

    while(temp!=NULL)

    {

        if(temp->vstd!=1)

        {

            dfs(temp);

        }

        temp=temp->nxt;

    }

}

void dpthfrst()

{

    struct node *temp;

    for(int v=0;v<5;v++)

    {

        temp=graph[v];

        while(temp!=NULL)

        {

            temp->vstd=0;

            temp=temp->nxt;

        }



    }

    for(int v=0;v<5;v++)

    {

        temp=graph[v];

        while(temp!=NULL)

        {

           if(temp->vstd!=1)

           dfs(temp);

           temp=temp->nxt;

        }

    }

}


void bfs(struct node *grtemp)

{

           struct node *head,*temp,*tmp2,*tmp3;

           ins(head,grtemp);

           do

           {

           temp=del(head);

           visited(temp);

           cout<<temp->dat<<endl;

           tmp2=temp->nxt;

           while(tmp2!=NULL)

           {

               tmp3=find(tmp2);

               ins(head,tmp3);

           }

           }while(!isemp(head));


}


void brthfrst()

{

    struct node *temp;

    for(int v=0;v<5;v++)

    {

        temp=graph[v];

        while(temp!=NULL)

        {

            temp->vstd=0;

            temp=temp->nxt;

        }


    }

    for(int v=0;v<5;v++)

    {

        temp=graph[v];

        while(temp!=NULL)
        {

           if(temp->vstd!=1)

           bfs(temp);

           temp=temp->nxt;

        }

    }

}

void insrtnode()

{

    struct node *temp;

    struct node *nnode=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));

    struct node *tnode=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));

    int s,d,f1=0,f2=0;

    cout<<"Insert the connection"<<endl;

    cin>>s;

    cin>>d;

    nnode->dat=s;

    nnode->nxt=NULL;

    nnode->vstd=0;

    tnode->dat=d;

    tnode->nxt=NULL;

    tnode->vstd=0;



    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)

    {

        if(graph[i]->dat==s)

            f1=1;

        if(graph[i]->dat==d)

            f2=1;



    }

    if(f1==0 && f2==0 && cnt<3)
    {

        for(int i=0;i<5;i++)

        {

            if(graph[i]==NULL)

            {

                graph[i]=nnode;

                graph[i]->nxt=tnode;

                graph[i++]=tnode;

                cnt+=2;

                break;

            }

        }

    }
   else if((f1==1 && f2==0 && cnt<4)||(f1==0 && f2 ==1 && cnt<4 ))


   {

       if(f1==1)

       {

           for(int i=0;i<5;i++)

           {

               if(graph[i]->dat==s)

               {

                   temp=graph[i];

                   while(temp->nxt!=NULL)

                    temp=temp->nxt;

                   temp->nxt=tnode;

               }

               if(graph[i]==NULL)

               {

                   graph[i]=tnode;

                   cnt++;

                   return;

               }

           }

       }

       if(f2==1)

       {
           for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
           {

               if(graph[i]==NULL)
               {
                   graph[i]=nnode;
                   graph[i]->nxt=tnode;
                   cnt++;
                   return;
               }
           }
       }
   }
       else

       {
           cout<<"Not a valid insertion";
           return;
       }
}

int main()
{
    initial();
    int ch;
    char ans;
    do
    {

        cout<<"1.INSERT\n 2.DFS \n 3.BFS\n";
        cin>>ch;
        switch(ch)
        {
            case 1: insrtnode();
                    break;
            case 2:dpthfrst();
                   break;
            case 3:brthfrst();
                   break;
            default :cout<<"Invalid \n";
        }
        cout<<"Do you want to continue?(y/n)";
        cin>>ans;
    }
    while(ans=='y'||ans=='Y'); 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: varaiable sized object graph cannot be initialised

Answer (score 0):

```
void initial()

{
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
        struct node *(graph[i])=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
}
```

in `struct node *(graph[i])`, you are accessing its `i` th position when you are declaring it. Should be like this

```
graph[i]=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
```

in insrtnode function

```
if(f1==0 && f2==0 && cnt<3)
    {

        for(int i=0;i<5;i++)

        {

            if(graph[i]==NULL)

            {

                graph[i]=nnode;

                graph[i]->nxt=tnode;

                graph[i++]=tnode;

                cnt+=2;

                break;

            }

        }

    }
```

the line

```
graph[i++]=tnode;
```

should be

```
graph[++i]=tnode;
```

Also try changing your variable names to a more meaningful one so that others can debug. Also put some comments in your code. Your original intention of this post was to remove the compilation error. And that is fixed. Now I suggest you to refactor your code and start debugging by yourself.

Comment: it still still not working properly at depthfrst function when it accesses temp->vstd, its showing segmentation error

Comment: where is the definition of the function `ins(head,grtemp);` ?

Comment: its in my own defined header file, that code is working perfectly fine